# Google maps api javascript crash safari when loading

Tags: google-maps-api-3, safari, crash

Google maps api javascript crash Safari browser (v7.0 - Mac OSX 9) when loading the page.
It crash when open the page on mobile (I've tried on iPhone 5 - chrome).

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
var panel;
var view;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39, -96),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var panelDiv = document.getElementById('panel');
var data = new StoreDataSource;
view = new storeLocator.View(map, data, {
    geolocation: true,
    features: data.getFeatures()
});

panel = new storeLocator.Panel(panelDiv, {
    view: view
});

google.maps.event.addListener(panel, 'stores_changed', setScrollbar);
});
</script>
```

On the code I'm loading store data (with statics location) and then insert on the map.
But even if I remove that part of the code, still crashing on Safari and mobile.

Here is the link of the page to test:

http://casamigostequila.com/pick-up-a-bottle/